# Paypal on multiple websites

Tags: paypal, payment

I would like to know if it was possible to sell products across multiple websites with a single paypal account?

I do not see any options on my management interface.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. PayPal makes it easy for sellers who use different brand names to manage multiple lines of business.

Therefore, you can setup your PayPal buttons or PayPal API to your individual websites.
For eg:
If you want to link your websites to your Single PayPal account for a Website Payment Standard button, then you just go ahead and create your button from PayPal(button factory)
and then use the generated button code in either of your websites.
Also,  it's easy to receive payment notifications and manage orders by using a different email address for the two lines of business. More info [here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/multiple_emails-outside)